# Problems with query in SQL*PLUS

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am getting a ORA-00923 (FROM keyword not found where expected) error when i run this query in sql*plus.

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME||' '||LAST_NAME AS FULLNAME
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE (JOB_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID) 
IN (SELECT JOB_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID FROM JOB_HISTORY)
AND DEPARTMENT_ID=80;
```

I ran that query in sql developer and guess what, it works without any problem, why I'm getting this error message when I try in sql*plus.

Comment: Just a query : Why are you using `DEPARTMENT_ID` in your where clause twice ? If the `DEPARTMENT_ID` has to be `80` the you can just retrieve the `job_id` in your inner query ?

Comment: In SQL Plus Client, You can break up your query to multiple lines to isolate the problem.

Comment: I know  but, i was just practice the subquery topic. I don't have the same database the book has so i make that query to practice that. xDDDDD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT   EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME AS FULLNAME
  FROM   EMPLOYEES
 WHERE   JOB_ID IN (SELECT   JOB_ID
                      FROM   JOB_HISTORY
                     WHERE   DEPARTMENT_ID = 80);
```

OR

```
SELECT   EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME AS FULLNAME
  FROM   EMPLOYEES
 WHERE   JOB_ID IN (SELECT   JOB_ID FROM JOB_HISTORY) AND DEPARTMENT_ID = 80;
```

OR

```
SELECT   EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME AS FULLNAME
  FROM   EMPLOYEES E
 WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT   NULL
                   FROM   JOB_HISTORY J
                  WHERE   J.JOB_ID = E.JOB_ID)
         AND DEPARTMENT_ID = 80;
```

Comment: This is way better than my answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

Your query is totally valid and runs in sqlplus exactly as it should:

```
14:04:01 (41)HR@sandbox> l
  1  SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME||' '||LAST_NAME AS FULLNAME
  2  FROM EMPLOYEES
  3  WHERE (JOB_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID)
  4  IN (SELECT JOB_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID FROM JOB_HISTORY)
  5* AND DEPARTMENT_ID=80
14:04:05 (41)HR@sandbox> /

34 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
```

You encounter ORA-00923 only when you have a syntax error. Like this:

```
14:04:06 (41)HR@sandbox> ed
Wrote file S:\spool\sandbox\BUF_HR_41.sql

  1  SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME||' '||LAST_NAME AS FULLNAME X
  2  FROM EMPLOYEES
  3  WHERE (JOB_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID)
  4  IN (SELECT JOB_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID FROM JOB_HISTORY)
  5* AND DEPARTMENT_ID=80
14:05:17 (41)HR@sandbox> /
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME||' '||LAST_NAME AS FULLNAME X
                                                           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Probably you made one while copying your query from sqldeveloper to sqlplus? Are you sure that your post contains exactly, symbol-to-symbol, the query you're actually trying to execute? I would pay more attention to query text and error message - it usually points at an error, like `*` under `X` in my example.

Comment: Thanks for the anawer. maybe it was a syntax error i didn't see, i ran the query again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve but here's a possible solution:

```
/* Formatted on 10/1/2013 1:50:20 PM (QP5 v5.126.903.23003) */
SELECT   EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME AS FULLNAME
  FROM      EMPLOYEES EMP
         JOIN
            JOB_HISTORY JH
         ON EMP.JOB_ID = JH.JOB_ID AND EMP.DEPARTMENT_ID = JH.DEPARTMENT_ID
 WHERE   EMP.DEPARTMENT_ID = 80;
```

Comment: `"I don't know what you are trying to achieve but here's a possible solution"` made me smile. no offence, sorry )

Comment: @beherenow, the question itself really lack explanation of what he really tries to achieve. Sorry.=D

Comment: Just practice with subqueries =)